# Using ExternalAccessory framework to advertise name and UUID over classic bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, mfi

In the CoreBluetooth library, CBPeripheralManager lets you advertise services when broadcasting your device. From the documentation:

> CBPeripheralManager objects are used to manage published services within the local peripheral device’s Generic Attribute Profile (GATT) database and to advertise these services to central devices (represented by 
>   CBCentral
>    objects). While a service is in the database, it is visible to, and can be accessed by, any connected central. That said, if your app has not specified the bluetooth-peripheral background mode, the contents of its services become disabled when it is in the background or in a suspended state; any remote central trying to access the service’s characteristic value or characteristic descriptors receives an error.

Is there a way to do this using classic bluetooth and the ExternalAccessory framework when attempting to broadcast a signal to a MFI device?